# Numerical integration in Matlab: matrix dimensions must agree?

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab to do the following numerical integration:

```
LB=0.3;
p_old=0.26;
C_TT_old=0.03;
r=0.63;
m=5.02;

integrand=@(d)(((r*m).^(r+1)*(r+1))/((d+r*m).^(r+2)))*(m.^2*C_TT_old*(1+(2*d*(1+r))/(m))-p_old*d+r*m*(log(d/(r*m)+1))*(p_old/r+p_old-2*C_TT_old*m*(1+r)))/((d+m)*(d+m-1)/2); 
C_old=integral(integrand,LB,Inf);
```

However, Matlab gives me the following error

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in
@(d)(((r*m).^(r+1)*(r+1))/((d+r*m).^(r+2)))*(m.^2*C_TT_old*(1+(2*d*(1+r))/(m))-p_old*d+r*m*(log(d/(r*m)+1))*(p_old/r+p_old-2*C_TT_old*m*(1+r)))/((d+m)*(d+m-1)/2)


Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] =
            iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 83)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

Could you help me to fix the code? I do not understand the source of the error as everything is scalar in my code.

Comment: you probably need to use scalar division `./` instead of matrix division `/`. Same for multiplication. When I change it in your code I get 0.0539

Comment: See: [the `integral` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#inputarg_fun): `For scalar-valued problems, the function y = fun(x) must accept a vector argument, x, and return a vector result, y. This generally means that fun must use array operators instead of matrix operators.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write the integrand in a way that it will deal with argument  'd' as vector. matlab will calculate the inegrand with vector, not with scalar.
So the soultion is  to use '.' notation in './' and '.*' and '.^' when you use  'd':

```
integrand=@(d)(((r*m)^(r+1)*(r+1))./((d+r*m).^(r+2))).*(m^2*C_TT_old*(1+(2*d.*(1+r))/m)-p_old*d+r*m*(log(d/(r*m)+1))*(p_old/r+p_old-2*C_TT_old*m*(1+r)))./((d+m).*(d+m-1)/2);
```